# Magento 1.4.2 Upload HTTP Error on CentOS

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Recently I upgraded Magento from 1.4.1 to 1.4.2 on CentOS and I have the issue where I can't upload images to the server through the WYSIWYG (Upload HTTP Error). I have researched the issue on numerous forums but none of the solutions work. Here is what I have tried:

Made sure the permissions are writable on media directory and tmp folder. I can create folders, just can't upload images.

Tried modifying the .htaccess in media folder:

```
#Options All -Indexes 
#Options -ExecCGI
```

I have tried turning this off suhosin in php.ini

```
suhosin.session.cryptua = off
```

I have tried adding a php.ini in Magento root with:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = off
short_open_tag = on
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

and tried adding this to the .htaccess as well:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type "^multipart/form-data;" "MODSEC_NOPOSTBUFFERING=Do not buffer file uploads"
```

I don't see errors in any of the log files, so I am totally stumped. 
Looking with firebug I see no network traffic when I click the upload file. So it makes me think that this is a JavaScript issue or a flash issue. 
I have replaced the prototype.js with 1.6 but that did nothing. Also giving full permissions to the flash uploader (/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media) did nothing.

Comment: We've had this issue in the past, but it only happend on certain browsers with certain versions of flash.

Comment: I am using the latest stable version of flash and have tried this in multiple browsers, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had such a problem once. It was connected with events in our custom modules. One of them was conflicting with the uploader module (the solution was to change its scope from global to frontend - but your case may be different). Try disabling all of your custom (/local/ and /community/)  modules using their XML configuration (set their value of 'enabled' to false or just move out the files from /etc/modules/ to /app/disabled/). If it helps just turn them on, one by one.

Another, similar situation happened when we used htaccess and rewrites to add/remove slashes to certain magento addresses.

Comment: This is not the problem. I disabled all modules and that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Actually you were correct. I tried removing all the modules again and this time it works. Thank you!